# UITableView Header (not section header) problem

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding iOS UITableView HeaderView (not section header)…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441938/adding-ios-uitableview-headerview-not-section-header)

I want to make a tableview header like in the contacts app:
[image]

Exactly like there, am image beside a label above the table.

Any way doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the double post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441938/adding-ios-uitableview-headerview-not-section-header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try a custom UIView with 2 subviews, a UIImageView and a UILabel, for a header?

Comment: Thanks, That worked for me! sorry for the double posts by mistake.