# "no index path for table cell being reused" issue for custom cell

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview, custom-cell

I am having a Tableview within that i have a custom cell and within that i have another tableview. In this `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method i am getting this error `no index path for table cell being reused` and `cell gets disappeared after scroll`. Is this indexpath issue or cellidentifier issue?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];     
//    __block CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    if (customCell == nil)
//    {
//        customCell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)] autorelease];
//   
// }
[customCell prepareCell:arrCategory];
return customCell;
}
-(void)prepareCell:(NSArray *)arrCategory
{
      if(mutArr != nil) {
        [mutArr removeAllObjects];
        mutArr = nil;
        [mutArr release];
 }
 mutArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrCategory];
 [tblCusom reloadData];
}
```

I go through [this SO ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772197/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-no-index-path-for-table-cell-being-reused-message-i) but i am not using the method used in this question. So what could be the problem I am not able to trace it. Also not found the same issue after googling

Answer (score 0):

If I right understood, you need check tableView (mainTableView or tblCustom) for which call method of delegate. 
Something like this:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (tableView == tblCusom)
        {
           __block CustomCell *categoryCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (customCell == nil)
            {
                customCell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)] autorelease];

            }

            [customCell prepareCell:arrCategory];
        }
        else if (tableView == self.myMainTableView)
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
            CustomCell *categoryCell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            return categoryCell;
        }

    return customCell;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have made different classes for all.SO this code is in that class where I am adjusting my internal cell with tableview within it

Comment: Ok, please show code where you create tblCustom. It may be in cellForRowAtIndexPath: for main tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this bug from a long time and found a solution :-

```
[tblCusom reloadData];
```

Replace it with

```
[self performSelector:@selector(tableReloadMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Add this method:-

```
-(void)tableReloadMethod
{
    [tblCusom reloadData];

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Very "hacky" solution, if you ever find yourself using delays to get around an issue, think twice. This answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12773104/250190, suggests it is a known internal bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CustomCell *categoryCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You are creating a cell instance but not using it anywhere,and that cell is returning from the reuseIdentifier method.So in fact no use of this line in your code

Comment: It was a typo..I am declaring CustomCell object and using it in preparecell method.Updated the question