# Expanding and Collapsing header cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The premise is simple. I have a `UITablewView`. I have a storyboard where I configured two prototype cells, one has a Reuse Identifier of headerCell, the other's Reuse Identifier is cell. I am instantiating a custom header cell like this in my `UITableViewController`:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    MyHeaderCell* headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headerCell"];
    headerCell.delegate = self;

    return headerCell;
}
```

My headerCell has a button on it, and when that button is tapped, it calls `[_delegate toggleHeaderSize]`. You can see above that the delegate property is simply the `UITableViewController`. Here is the `toggleHeaderSize` method:

```
-(void)toggleHeaderSize {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (headerHeight == 100) {
        headerHeight = 120;
    } else {
        headerHeight = 100;
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

//    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

That headerHeight variable is used in the `heightForHeaderInSection` method, like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return headerHeight;
}
```

The header changes size, but it's weird. The table slides down, but the header doesn't actually grow. If I scroll the table just one pixel, the header seems to realize it needs to redraw, and it snaps to size.

I think I've read about every SO post about resizing header cells. They all seem to think the magic is with the `beginUpdates/endUpdates` dance. These do seem to be necessary, but it doesn't solve the problem of redrawing.

Here's an animated GIF of my problem.
EDIT: I can't post the animated GIF since I don't have 10 reputation points, but if you go to http://nspaul.imgur.com/all/ you can find it  :-)

I'd love any guidance. I can post more code if someone would like. I'll even post the whole project to `Github` if that helps.

Comment: what do you want increase your headerCell height or your tableview header height?

Comment: Since I a using the headerCell in `viewForHeaderInSection`, wouldn't that make headerView the tableviewHeader? Or, is there a significant difference between the headerCell and the tableview header? If there's a better way to do this, please let me know. The goal here is to make that cell, which I am using as the header, bigger, and have it animate.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)toggleHeaderSize {
    if (headerHeight == 100) {
        headerHeight = 120;
    } else {
        headerHeight = 100;
    }    
    [self.tableView reloadSections:mySections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation];
}
```

Methods `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` only create transaction for animations. You need method which will reload affected sections.

Comment: I tried adding a call to that method, which in my case looks like this:
`[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`
The headerCell just disappears, and I get `no index path for table cell being reused` twice in my console.

Comment: Try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490621/no-index-path-for-table-cell-being-reused