# uitableview how to parse data multiple cell dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c

**please suggest me how to display data like tree view.**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return marrSearchResult.count;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   int iCount=0;

    if (section==0) {

        iCount =(int)[marrSearchResult count];
    }else if(section==1){

        iCount =(int)[[[[marrSearchResult objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"result"] count]+1;
    }else{

    }
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyTravelProfileTblCELL";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    }else{
    }
}
```

**see below image desplay like this**
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the data you getting i.e. marrSearchResult ??

Comment: [
   {
       "title": "ENTERTAINMENT",
        "data": [
            {
                "type_title": "Restaurants",
                "result": [
                    {
   "place_data": [
                            {
                                "name": "Tim Hortons",
                                "address": "1910 Yonge St",
                                "number": "+1 416-481-0209",
                                "website": “www.google.com”
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

Comment: @luckyShubhra please check above array

Comment: your json doesnot seems to be valid.. Check and update

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps :

- Create custom tableview cell for section header (Tourist attractions, Government/Community). Lets call it PlaceTypeCell
- Create another custom tableview cell for rows (Museums, Hospitals... ). Lets call it PlaceNameCell.
- Return the section count as the count of main array (you already did it)
- Return the row count as the count of subarray at the index of section in the main array (also you did it)
- Now in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, get the sub array from main based on section number (`indexPath.section`). Now get the required row item(Place name and details) from sub array using row number (`indexPath.row`). Using the data in that row item populate the table cell.
- Now in the `viewForHeaderInSection` get the place type details from the main array using section number and populate the PlaceTypeCell and return as section header. Have a look at [Best way to create custom UITableview section header in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577486/best-way-to-create-custom-uitableview-section-header-in-storyboard)
- Set the height for section header using `heightForHeaderInSection`

Hope it helps.

Edit : If you can show the format of marrSearchResult, then it will be easy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Create Input array in Format:

```
NSArray *tourismSection = @[@"Museums", @"Aquariums"];
NSArray *govSection = @[@"Hopsital"];

NSDictionary *data = @{
     @"tourism" : tourismSection,
     @"gov"     : govSection
};
NSArray *inputs = @[@"tourism",@"gov" ];
```

in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

```
return inputs.count;
```

in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
return [data valueForKey:inputs[indexPath.section]].count;
```