# Custom header of table view with IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, uistoryboard

I would like to create a custom header for a table view section with interface builder. I cannot use the method *titleForHeaderInSection* because i need to display two labels. I used this instructions: [Customizing Header and Footer of TableView in iOS8](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift) but it does not work.

What I have done so far:

1. Create a custom class CustomTableCell which inherits from UITableViewCell

```
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
}
```

1. Create a dynamic prototype cell in storyboard
2. Add an identifier
3. Connect the labels to the custom UITableViewCell
4. Implement `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableCell") as CustomTableCell
    headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    headerCell.dateLabel.text = "Test date"
    headerCell.dateDescriptionLabel.text = "Test date description"

    return headerCell
}
```

When i run the app the section appears one second and then moves under the table cells and I get an error: **no index path for table cell being reused**.

What is wrong with this solution? I downloaded the project from the tutorial I have linked and it works there.

Comment: did you set the delegate &  datasource of the tableView?

Comment: Yes sure. Otherwise the header sections wouldn't be shown for one second

Comment: can you add the logs of the error?

Comment: 015-02-15 17:39:01.791 MyApp[16701:530127] no index path for table cell being reused  2015-02-15 17:39:01.791 MyApp[16701:530127] no index path for table cell being reused

Comment: it seems like you are doing something wrong in another method call, can you add you project to gitHub and share a link? ill go though it

Comment: I found the mistake. When you add `self.tableView.reloadData()
tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .None)`   i get the error but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: didn't understand.. you got a new error?

Comment: No the same error. I removed the two lines and then I get no errors. The problem now is that the height of the self sizing table view is not correct. http://github.com/Aigai0s/CustomSectionHeader

Comment: I complied your code, it works perfectly..no errors..

Comment: Then click on the right bar button and the error will occur

Comment: try removing this statement tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .None). I got no error & the tableView did reload

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to find another solution because now my layout is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has its roots in how UIKit handles UITableViews.
To make sure table views are fast and responsive, even with a large amount of cells, the cells are re-used.

By calling `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableCell")` you are asking the tableView to give you a cell to reuse.

A lot of people have been using the reusable cells to design their headers/footers in Storyboards. Ever since iOS 7 Beta 5 this may lead to errors. This answer explains the situation well: [What is the meaning of the “no index path for table cell being reused” message in iOS 6/7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769328/2557273)

To design your own custom header/footer views I don't recommend using UITableViewCells. Instead you should create and design a custom UIView directly in your code. If you want to use Interface Builder you could create a .xib or create a view in your Storyboard that is not a subview of the actual controller's view.

Comment: I will create .xib file. Thank you for your help.