# After fixing error `no index path for table cell being reused` , section header cells don't fit the view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

In `Main.storyboard` my section header cell has a height of `50` I would change that programmatically by the method in my `UITableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return normalCellHeight
}
```

At the same time, I was getting the error `no index path for table cell being reused`, so I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772197/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-no-index-path-for-table-cell-being-reused-message-i) to fix my error.

But after I fixed that error using [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772197/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-no-index-path-for-table-cell-being-reused-message-i), now my section headers aren't resized to fit the view. It [used to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCMRz.png), but now it [looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGv7I.png) As you can see my section headers don't fit the height and go over the screen width-wise.

I know I can fix the height issue by setting the height of my section header cells in `Main.storyboard` to `76`. But that's not ideal, since I want all my section header cells to fill up the entire height of the view and the height of each individual header cell would change from an iPhone 5 to an iPhone 6. And [you can see, it doesn't fix the width issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2TR7.png), which is strange b/c the view's width and the header view's frame width are the same (seen below). [If relevant here is my storyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWFN9.png)

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    normalCellHeight = (view.bounds.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height - 15)/(CGFloat(self.dayOfWeek.count) + 1)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == lastCellIndex{
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("allExpensesCell") as!AllExpensesCell
        let view = UIView(frame: header.frame)
        view.addSubview(header)
        return view
    } else{
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") as!
        SummaryHeaderTableViewCell
        header.delegate = self
        header.index = section
        let day = dayOfWeek[section]
        header.dayOfWeek.text = day.rawValue.uppercaseString
        header.dayOfWeek.backgroundColor = colorOfDay[day]
        header.totalCost.text = "$\(totalSpentPerDay[section])"
        header.totalCostView.backgroundColor = colorOfDay[day]
        let view = UIView(frame: header.frame)
        print("Header frame height: \(header.frame.height)")
        print("Header frame width: \(header.frame.width)")
        print("Screen width: \(view.bounds.width)")
        view.addSubview(header)
        return view
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    print("Header height: \(normalCellHeight)")
    return normalCellHeight
}
```

Console:

```
Header height: 76.0 //This prints 48 times
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header height: 76.0
Header frame height: 50.0 //These 3 lines print 7 times, which makes sense b/c I have 7 sections
Header frame width: 600.0
Screen width: 600.0
Header frame height: 50.0
Header frame width: 600.0
Screen width: 600.0
Header frame height: 50.0
Header frame width: 600.0
Screen width: 600.0
Header frame height: 50.0
Header frame width: 600.0
Screen width: 600.0
Header frame height: 50.0
Header frame width: 600.0
Screen width: 600.0
Header frame height: 50.0
Header frame width: 600.0
Screen width: 600.0
Header frame height: 50.0
Header frame width: 600.0
Screen width: 600.0
```

Comment: Why are you creating a view and then adding the header to that view? Why not just return `header`? `UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView` after all.

Comment: b/c I was getting the error "no index path for table cell being reuse" and as this post suggested (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772197/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-no-index-path-for-table-cell-being-reused-message-i) I should return a UIView instead of UITableViewCell

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with autolayout. Maybe you need to set your autoresize mask like this: `header.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]` and then make sure that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`