# How to change height of grouped UITableView header?

Tags: ios, uikit, tableview, uitableview

I know how to change the height of the section headers in the table view.  But I am unable to find any solution to change the default spacing before the first section.

Right now I have this code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return 10;
}
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441938/adding-ios-uitableview-headerview-not-section-header See this link...

Comment: @JitendraDeore Thanks for guiding me in the right direction

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears that I can't set a table header view with height of 0.  I ended up doing the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView];
}
```

Comment: This would be better to set height at here: `- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    return 1.0f;
}`

Answer (score 225):

Return `CGFLOAT_MIN` instead of 0 for your desired section height.

> Returning 0 causes UITableView to use a default value. This is
>   undocumented behavior. If you return a very small number, you
>   effectively get a zero-height header.

Swift 3:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == 0 {
            return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
        }
        return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
    }
```

Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return CGFloat.min
    }
    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}
```

Obj-C:

```
    - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return CGFLOAT_MIN;
    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight;
}
```

Comment: In Swift,'CGFLOAT_MIN' is unavailable: use CGFloat.min instead.

Comment: CGFloat.min caused a crash, because CGFloat.min returns negative value like -0.0000000000001

Comment: I dont't have any problem with CGFloat.min. Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Yep the aproach with CGFloat.min works like a charm! Do not forget to also set the footer view nil.... They also have a height in grouped table views!

Comment: Perhaps this is pedantry, but CGFloat.min is not a very small number, it's a very large negative number. If you wanted a very small number you would use epsilon.

Comment: In Swift 3 it’s `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`

Comment: Advise: Dont use this value on `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection`, the app will crash.

Comment: If you want `heightForHeaderInSection` is called you'll need to return `nil` in `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: the question was about a GROUPED tableView style.  These solutions don't work for that.

Answer (score 31):

If you use `tableView` style **grouped**, `tableView` automatically set top and bottom insets. To avoid them and avoid internal insets setting, use delegate methods for header and footer. **Never return 0.0 but `CGFLOAT_MIN`**.

#### Objective-C

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Removes extra padding in Grouped style
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Removes extra padding in Grouped style
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

#### Swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // Removes extra padding in Grouped style
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // Removes extra padding in Grouped style
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Comment: I additionally had to **return nil** for `viewForHeaderInSection` for the header to fully disappear.

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me with **Swift 4**. Modify your `UITableView` e.g. in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// Remove space between sections.
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0

// Remove space at top and bottom of tableView.
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude)))
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude)))
```

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks for taking the time to mention it here :)

Answer (score 13):

You can try this:

In the `loadView`

```
_tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
```

Then

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0;
}
```

It should be removed as long as you do not have any objects in the header...

And if you want some size of the sectionheader, then change only the return value.

same if you do not get the sectionfooter removed.

```
_tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0;
```

and

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0;
}
```

Well, this works for my problems with the tableview in the iOS7.

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the code `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [UIView new];` after you add

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Comment: It is `footer` height which is causing issue in my case. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4

Remove extra top padding in grouped tableview.

Here height is given 1 as minimal height for the section header because you cannot give 0 as tableview will take it default top margin if assigned zero height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `viewForHeaderInSection` and return a view with any height.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    int height = 30 //you can change the height 
    if(section==0)
    {
       UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height)];

       return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking about section headers, but the table header.

Comment: then you can directly pass A uiview to the table header view.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 2.0

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return yourHeight
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are enough.

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0
```

For me, it is working in Xcode 12.2, iOS 14.2

Answer (score 0):

Example of viewForHeaderInSection:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 118)];
view.backgroundColor = COLOR_DEFAULT;

NSString* key = [self.tableKeys objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *result = (NSArray*)[self.filteredTableData objectForKey:key];
SZTicketsResult *ticketResult = [result objectAtIndex:0];

UIView *smallColoredView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 320, 3)];
smallColoredView.backgroundColor = COLOR_DEFAULT_KOSTKY;
[view addSubview:smallColoredView];

UIView *topBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 8, 320, 40)];
topBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:248.0/255.0 blue:174.0/255.0 alpha:1];
[view addSubview:topBackgroundView];

UILabel *totalWinnings = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 300, 40)];
totalWinnings.text = ticketResult.message;
totalWinnings.minimumFontSize = 10.0f;
totalWinnings.numberOfLines = 0;
totalWinnings.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
totalWinnings.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
[view addSubview:totalWinnings];

UIView *bottomBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 58)];
bottomBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:248.0/255.0 blue:174.0/255.0 alpha:1];
[view addSubview:bottomBackgroundView];

UILabel *numberOfDraw = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 55, 290, 58)];
numberOfDraw.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sometext %@",[ticketResult.title lowercaseString]];;
numberOfDraw.minimumFontSize = 10.0f;
numberOfDraw.numberOfLines = 0;
numberOfDraw.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
numberOfDraw.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
[view addSubview:numberOfDraw];

return view;
```