# How can I hide section headers in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In iOS 11, my section headers always appear, regardless of whether the items are 0 or more.

On iOS 10 devices, my code works and sections disappear when item count is 0. But on iOS 11, the same code has no affect.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if sections[section].items.count > 0{
        return sections[section].title
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you possibly implementing heightForHeaderInSection or viewForHeaderInSection? That could make your sections appear or not. Also apple docs say about titleForHeaderInSection "Return Value: A string to use as the title of the section header. If you return nil , the section will have no title." Doesn't say there will be no section, only no title.

Answer (score 10):

In iOS 11 if you implement only `titleForHeaderInSection` and return nil, you will not see a header view. But if you also implement `viewForHeaderInSection`, regardless of what you return, there will be a section.

This alone will not show a section header:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return nil
}
```

This will show a section header with no title:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return nil
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

So both methods may return nil and the header will be visible. If only `titleForHeaderInSection` is implemented, no header shows up. That does seem to be a case only in iOS 11. Not sure if it's a bug or a way to force developers chose one method of the two. But the docs confirm this behaviour about `titleForHeaderInSection`:

> "Return Value: A string to use as the title of the section header. If you return nil , the section will have no title."

So nothing about showing or not showing, this method only returns the string for the title. Which makes sense. But what does look like a bug is that returning nil in `viewForHeaderInSection` will show the section header.

Comment: Wow. This seems to be a major bug.

Comment: It does look more like a bug than a feature :)

Answer (score 5):

To hide a section header for, say, section 0, implement the following method like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if (section == 0) {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude //Now section 0's header is hidden regardless of the new behaviour in iOS11.
    }

    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}
```

This solution also works for grouped UITableViews, as discussed below.

**Update**: If you execute reloadSections(..), this solution causes an

> NSException of type 'CALayerInvalidGeometry'

If you `return 0` in the `if` statement however, this crash doesn't occur! :)

Therefore, I would say the best solution I have found (atleast for plain `UITableViews`) is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 0
    }

    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}
```

Comment: Returning 0 causes UITableView to use a default value. This is
undocumented behavior. If you return a very small number, you
effectively get a zero-height header.

Comment: That's not my experience. My experience is that returning 0 suppresses the header.

Comment: It may have changed in a recent version of iOS, but this was definitely an issue in the past. It may also depend on whether you use a grouped UITableView or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699831/how-to-change-height-of-grouped-uitableview-header

Comment: Okay, I definitely am not talking about a grouped table view.

Comment: Well, that is a common type so it may be relevant to others.

Comment: `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` was needed (and still is, I believe) for grouped tables. It is problematic with plain tables though. It's magic out there.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` to return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

This will suppress the section header in exactly the case where `titleForHeaderInSection` returns `nil` (and otherwise it will use the default header height from the table).

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly tell iOS 11 to use a height of 0 in `heightForHeaderInSection` it will hide the section header. You can still use automatic header sizing by returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for non-zero height headers. Here's an example of a solution to workaround the iOS 11 bug:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
  guard shouldShowSectionHeader(section: section) else { return 0 }
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

You'll need to implement `shouldShowSectionHeader` to determine whether or not to show the section header.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11.3, works in production

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    return sections[section].headerViewModel?.makeView(bindImmediately: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return sections[section].headerViewModel == nil ? 0 : UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

return empty view from `viewForHeaderInSection`

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3, 4 and 4.2**

To hide your tableView header

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect.zero
```

and to show it back

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 66)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.01
}
```