# How to unfix tableview section header in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

So i have sticky header at the top of view. Then i have table view. It starts from y:135

I need to do something to allow first section header to sroll up with its content. How i can make it?

I decide to make table view padding top if it possible, and than start table view from x:0 y:0

OR

To unfix section header and allow to scroll with content, or maybe there is another way to do that? Here is my screens:

[image]

[image]

OR Maybe the correct way will be to FAKE fist section with custom row height? and make it unvisible, and it will be my padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> allow first section header to sroll up with its content

It's related to `UITableViewStyle`.
When the `UITableViewStyle` property of the table is set to `UITableViewStylePlain`. If you have it set to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, the headers will scroll up with the cells. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582818/uitableview-with-fixed-section-headers).

> to FAKE fist section with custom row height?

I am not sure that it's a good solution.

Comment: Thanks allot! so i decided to make UITableViewStyleGrouped, but now i have some extra paddings in section headers. In my screens it was 36 height, but now i guess it much more than 36. Can i manage it?

Comment: @WhoIsDT please look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699831/how-to-change-height-of-grouped-uitableview-header) and also check `heightForFooterInSection` maybe you use it somewhere.

Comment: tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0 - thats completely helped! Thank you very much!