# Adding both header and TableViewCell to TableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

To add a header to my tableView I follow @KirbyTodd's answer at [Adding iOS UITableView HeaderView (not section header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441938/adding-ios-uitableview-headerview-not-section-header). Now I want to add a TableViewCell to my table. But when I drop the cell in the TableView, the cell appears above my header. Does anyone know how I might correctly add both a header and a custom cell to my TableView using the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You added not `tableHeaderView`, but `tableFooterView`. If you add `tableHeaderView` it appears above all content.