# AMSlideMenu: How to customize the menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amslidemenu

I am using AMSlideMenu and want to customize the menu a little bit. Namely, I want to move the menu items down, add a UIImage above them, add a custom button above the menu items, and create a background image for the entire thing.

I thought it would be as simple as adding the items I want to the slide menu view controller in Storyboards, but the way the menu works requires the menu to be a Table View Controller rather than a standard View Controller containing a UITableView.

I do not have experience creating custom controllers or using XIB files, so I am not sure if these would be a solution. Has anyone tried adding something like this to AMSlideMenu, and do you have any general suggestions/links to tutorials for building custom interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tableView's header or footer views to add your custom controls.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441938/adding-ios-uitableview-headerview-not-section-header)