# Add UIView to UITableView's header not in section's header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am using `UITableView`'s which contains two section (color and animals)
but I want to two `UIButton`s at tableview's header not in `UITableView`'s section's header

Can you please help me :) thanks

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441938/adding-ios-uitableview-headerview-not-section-header

Comment: Go through This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to drag and drop `UIView` in your IB and outlet it and set

```
yourtable.tableHeaderView = youroutletview;
```

[image]

Now you can customize view as you want.