# Button stays at top of UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a UITableViewController, and that works fine but I don't understand how I can put a button at the top of it, which doesn't move? I've already got a search input at the top, but I need a button to be  under it which will re-sort the table contents.

Comment: I suggest that you should use a `UIViewController` with a view inside it and a search field. `UITableViewController`'s vie it's a `UITableView`, when you try to add a subview to `.view` it will be added to the `UITableView` that's why it's moving.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to the header view (the details of doing this programmatically are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442005/335858); you can do it through IB, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442267/335858)).

I prefer the IB way - open the properties of your table's header view, and add a view with your search input and a sort button to it.