# UITableView Section Header Stay Anchored for All Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with many sections. It is a simple table view. I am using viewForHeaderInSection to create custom views for these headers. So far, so good.

The default scrolling behavior is that when a section is encountered, the section header stays anchored below the Nav bar, until the next section scrolls into view.

My question is this: can I change the default behavior so that the first section header stay anchored at the top for all sections?

Thanks.

**Desired Behavior image url:**

## https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lnspddx02aku1n/scroll.png?dl=0

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this in any straightforward way. You'll probably need to subclass UITableView and add the special first-section-header view as an "anchored" view.

Comment: this might help you.  if it does, you can delete this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441938/adding-ios-uitableview-headerview-not-section-header

Comment: @danh I'm hoping that the header view does not scroll up with the rest of view as tableHeaderView does..

Comment: Do you want that first section header to scroll at all?

Comment: @riven, I think what AdamPro13 is getting at is, that if you don't want the section header behavior, and you don't want the tableView header behavior, then maybe what you really want is an independent view that sits over the table.  It needn't be related to the table at all.

Comment: This question looks like it needs a picture or two to explain the desired behavior, because it's very unclear.

Comment: @danh that's exactly what I was getting at. Add the "first section header" view as a subview of the table view and adjust the contentInset of the table view so that the content will start under the "section header" when the user is scrolled to the top of the table view.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lnspddx02aku1n/scroll.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by augmenting the header/data relationship. You can have a section header on even numbered sections, and data in odd numbered sections.

Example: For section 0, you can show the appropriate heading, but have 0 rows in that section. The data for section 0 should show up in section 1. Section 1 will not have a header. etc etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how this could make the first section header stick to the top.

Comment: I saw the dropbox image now. That clarified it a bit for me. Is there any separator between the first and second sections? Dropbox image has a black line. What if you just had 1 section and the cells in all other sections are basically in the first section. Would that solve it?

Comment: That occurred to me as well. However I also want the index bar feature of tableview, which can only be done if there are multiple sections... @Roderic Campbell

Comment: In that case perhaps you could use a custom index bar implementation, perhaps similar to this: https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar