# how can I refresh a single button in UITableViewCell instead of refreshing whole table or whole cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

In my `swift` app I have a `UITableView` with one static cell and many dynamic cells.

Static cell contains different fields, such as labels, map (taken from `MapKit`) and a button, that indicates whether user voted up or not.

Now, when user presses the button, I want to change its color, possibly without refreshing anything else.

So far my code looks like this:

```
var currentUserVote:Int = 0

func tableView(_ tview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {
        let cell = tview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellStatic") as! VideoDetailsCell

        fetchScore(cell.score)

        let voteUpImage = UIImage(named: "voteUp");
        let tintedVoteUpImage = voteUpImage?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        cell.voteUpButton.setImage(tintedVoteUpImage, for: UIControlState())

        checkUsersVote() { responseObject in

            if(responseObject == 1) {

                cell.voteUpButton.tintColor = orangeColor

            } else if (responseObject == -1){
                cell.voteUpButton.tintColor = greyColor

            } else {
                cell.voteUpButton.tintColor = greyColor

            } 

            self.currentUserVote = responseObject
        }

        //map handling:
        let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation, map: cell.mapView, radius: regionRadius)
        //cell.mapView.isScrollEnabled = false
        cell.mapView.delegate = self
        .
        .
        . 
        return cell
        } else {
        //handle dynamic cells
        }
}
```

So in the method above I'm checking if user voted already and based on that I'm setting different color on the button. I'm also centering the map on a specific point.

Now, since it's a static cell, I connected `IBAction` outlet to that button:

```
@IBAction func voteUpButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     if(currentUserVote == 1) {
        self.vote(0)
    }else if (currentUserVote == -1){
        self.vote(1)
    } else {
        self.vote(1)
    }
}
```

and the `vote` method works as follows:

```
func vote(_ vote: Int){

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    let cell = tview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellStatic") as! VideoDetailsCell


    switch(vote) {
    case 1:
        cell.voteUpButton.tintColor = orangeColor
    case 0:
        cell.voteUpButton.tintColor = greyColor
    case -1:
        cell.voteUpButton.tintColor = greyColor
    default:
        cell.voteUpButton.tintColor = greyColor
    }

    tview.beginUpdates()
    tview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tview.endUpdates()

    currentUserVote = vote

    //sending vote to my backend
}
```

My problem is, that when user taps the button, he invokes the method `vote`, then - based on the vote, the button changes color, but immediately after that method `cellForRow` is called and it changes the color of the button again. Also, it refreshes the map that's inside of it.

What I want to achieve is that when user taps the button, it should immediately change its color and that's it. Map stays untouched and the button is not changed again from `cellForRow`.

Is there a way of refreshing only that particular button without calling again `cellForRow`?

Comment: your checkUsersVote() should return the updated value of vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you confuse static and dynamic cells. You can use static cells only in the `UITableViewController` and you can't use static and dynamic cell at the same time.
2. I strongly recommend you not to use cell for storing map and button. All elements from the cell will be released after scrolling it beyond the screen.

I can advise you use `TableViewHeaderView` for this task. In this case you will be able set button and map view as `@IBOutlet`.

(See more about [adding tableview headerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442005/4315868). You can also set it from interface builder.)

Another way is change `tableView.contentInset` and set your view with map and button as subview to `tableView`. This method is used when you need create [Stretchy Headers](http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-stretchy-headers/).

[image]

Comment: hm, so after hitting the button, do I have to refresh the `headerView` ?

Comment: No, you can relate `vote` button as `@IBOutset` to your `viewController` and in `vote` method just set its color/image/state/etc. You can also center mapView in this method. And you don't need reload tableView.

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite easy, simply do it in your button handler. The `sender` argument there is the button object that caused the action. When you were connecting it from IB there was a dropdown to select sender type, you may have missed it and the whole thing would have been obvious with `UIButton` type there.

Simply change your handler like this :

```
@IBAction func voteUpButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     if(currentUserVote == 1) {
        self.vote(0)
    }else if (currentUserVote == -1){
        self.vote(1)
    } else {
        self.vote(1)
    }
    sender.backgroundColor = yourFavouriteColor
}
```

Another approach would be to create an `IBOutlet` for your button, since its from a static cell, and then you would be able to reference it from any place in your view controller.

Comment: but the key thing - if you don't want to update anything other than the button - is remove the lines where you `reloadRows`

Comment: Yes, I just assumed this was obvious ;)

Comment: hm @Losiowaty that makes sense! So... There's also a `voteDown` button - can I access it from the `voteUpButtonAction` and change its color from there too?

Comment: Yeas, as I said - you can crate `IBOutlets` for UI elements from static cells (same way as you'd go about crating an `IBAction`, there also should be a dropdown, and an outlet is a default option I think). The instead of `sender` you can use `self.voteUpButton` and `self.voteDownButton` or howevee you choose to name them, sven outside of the button handling methods.

Answer (score 0):

In this call:

func tableView(_ tview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

I see it calls checkUsersVote() which I'm guessing should get the updated value set in the vote() call. Could the problem be that you aren't doing this 
    currentUserVote = vote
until after reloadRows() is called?